# Where is so much additional memory used in mapper (Hadoop mapreduce)?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I've written a simple app, that has an .csv file as an input, converts its every line into xml somehow simply, and then outputs it as single line. Everything is described is done in mapper. I have no reducers: *job.setNumReduceTasks(0);*

I run everything locally, i'm just studying Hadoop.
I want to explore the memory consumption. Therefore I've set no limits for the heap: very big Xmx. And i try to process a huge file: 2.5G.

I use Java Mission Control profiler.
The results are really interesting (at least for me). Heap never exceeded 3.3G. But the maximum just before garbage collection was always the same around this value of 3.3G. And after the GC it falls down to zero.

My question may be a bit silly, but what is this overhead of 3.3-2.5=0.8G is used for? Unfortunately, information in JMC didn't help with it. It shows obvious Hot Classes: String and char. It would be great if you point me to the hadoop  classes where the most of the memory is used.

Comment: There could be more information available in JMC, look at the Memory/Allocations tab, on the Allocation in New TLAB subtab (or the Outside TLAB) subtab. There you get the stacktraces for the allocations. (Also note that these subtabs in turn are divided into three subtabs each, for example Allocation Profile, which might be what you want) The actual classes allocated are probably String and char, so you just have to find where they are allocated...

Comment: @Klara , very thanks! I'm quite new to JMC, and haven't found this options. That is what i exactly need